# Storyboard & Seque: How does the presenting VC know when the presented VC dismisses itself?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have a two scene StoryBoard in my app - it uses an automatic segue (created in IB). When a button is clicked in the 1st `UIViewController` the 2nd `UIViewController` is presented modally.

The 1st `UIViewController` needs to know when second the 2nd `UIViewController` dismisses itself. What is the correct way to achieve this? Right now, I'm using `-viewDidAppear:` in the 1st vc but that doesn't seem right.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Best,
CS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing, plus checking that `isMovingToParentViewController` is NO, should work for this specific case.  It won't help if you ever have other view controllers that are triggered from the first one and you want to distinguish among them.

The most direct method would be to have the modal controller post a notification when it is going away.

Answer (score 1):

You could use notifications to ensure that you only perform the task on vc2 dismissal.

```
// in vc1
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doSomethingWhenVC2Dismissed) name:@"vc_2_dismissed" object:nil];

// in vc2
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"vc_2_dismissed" object:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply follow the way Apple does it with the SDK supplied ViewControllers intended to be presented modally: MFMailComposer, UIImagePicker, etc.

Use delegation.